# Which formats are supported for icon and splash screen in Android ? Also can i use max size image for all the screens?

Tags: android

as per android developers docs, 96 X 96 px is the icon size required for high density screens . Can i use the same size icon for all the screens? or I have to provide different sizes for different screens like ldpi, mdpi . Also, png is the only format accepted or any format accepted ?

Also for splash screen, 1440 X 1080 px is for xlarge screens, so can I use this single image for all the other screens (like large, normal and small) Or do i have to provide separate images for all the screens ?  Also, what formats are supported?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please read about [how to support multiple screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

```
xlarge screens are at least 960dp x 720dp
large screens are at least 640dp x 480dp
normal screens are at least 470dp x 320dp
small screens are at least 426dp x 320dp
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use separate images and separate layouts to handle different screen sizes. Otherwise for xlarge screens the image may be fine but for small screens it will get cropped. Same will happen with layouts. So for best programming experience please use separate files. Android supports files other than .png as well.

Answer (score 1):

If you use one icon then Android system will stretch and set it for all other resolution. problem is your icon is stretch for large screen. then, it might causes to appearance of the application. so you have to think this.

if you use each icon for each display size, it may causes to apk file size. this is the same thing about other images that adding for different display sizes.so you have to consider this.

most of the time you can manage this with 9patch images to avoid this.

with my experience, I have notice that avoiding images that have circles makes not to use different images for different screen sizes.then you can manage it with less images.When they are stretched circles become ellipse.

I think now you have idea.